# Flask creates new session every request even on same browser

Tags: python, flask, session, backend, spotify

I'm developing an application where that uses Spotify's web api and I want to use Session to save the access and refresh tokens. I use Flask (I'm a beginner) as the backend and React.js as the front end. The problem is every time a new request is made to my flask server, it creates a new session id and replaces the old one even though I'm using the same browser (I checked the Set-cookie response headers and they are different e.g. session=ejfeawcawd and session=ejfeagthysfawd) . It's a problem because I'm no longer able to make api requests with flask on behalf of the user.

Here's how I call my api (I can't use fetch or axios cuz I need it to redirect me to the spotify permissions page):

```
export default function loginSpotify() {
   const requestURL = 'http://127.0.0.1:5001/spotify_login'
   window.location = requestURL
}
```

Here's my flask code:

```
# imports
# ...

load_dotenv('./.env')

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SWAGGER'] = {'ui_params': {'displayRequestDuration': 'true'}, }
CORS(app)

app.secret_key = b'secretkeyhere'

swagger = Swagger(app)

# Database info
app.config['MYSQL_HOST'] = os.getenv('MYSQL_HOST')
app.config['MYSQL_USER'] = os.getenv('MYSQL_USER')
app.config['MYSQL_PASSWORD'] = os.getenv('MYSQL_PASSWORD')
app.config['MYSQL_DB'] = os.getenv('MYSQL_DB')

mysql = MySQL(app)

TABLE_NAME = 'track'


REDIRECT_URI = 'http://localhost:5001/callback'
SPOTIFY_CLIENT_ID = os.environ.get("SPOTIFY_CLIENT_ID")
SPOTIFY_CLIENT_SECRET = os.environ.get('SPOTIFY_CLIENT_SECRET')
CLIENT_REDIRECT = 'http://localhost:5173/recommender'
# API routes

@app.route("/spotify_login")
def spotify_login():
    auth_endpoint = 'https://accounts.spotify.com/authorize?'
    scope = "playlist-modify-private+playlist-modify-public"
    choices = string.ascii_letters + string.digits
    state = ''.join(secrets.choice(choices)for i in range(16))
    session['state'] = state
    print(session)
    print(request.cookies)
    session.modified = True
    return redirect(f'{auth_endpoint}response_type=code&client_id={SPOTIFY_CLIENT_ID}&'
                    f'scope={scope}&state={state}&redirect_uri={REDIRECT_URI}')


@app.route("/callback")
def get_tokens():
    code = request.args.get('code')
    state = request.args.get('state')

    if (state is None) and (state != session['state']):
    # if (state is None) or (state != session['state']):
        return redirect('/#?error=state_mismatch')
    else:
        url = 'https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token'
        headers = {
            'Authorization': 'Basic ' + base64.b64encode(bytes(f"{SPOTIFY_CLIENT_ID}:{SPOTIFY_CLIENT_SECRET}", 'utf-8'))
            .decode('utf-8')
        }
        data = {
            'code': code,
            'redirect_uri': REDIRECT_URI,
            'grant_type': 'authorization_code'
        }

        res = requests.post(url, data=data, headers=headers)

        if res.ok:
            data = res.json()
            session['access_token'] = data['access_token']
            session['refresh_token'] = data['refresh_token']
            print(session)
            print(request.cookies)
            session.modified = True
        else:
            print(f"Error: {res.status_code}\n{res.text}")

        return redirect(CLIENT_REDIRECT)


@app.route("/is_logged_in")
def is_logged_in():
    logged_in = 'access_token' in session
    print(session)
    print(request.cookies)
    return {'logged_in': logged_in}

if __name__ == "__main__":
    serve(app, host="0.0.0.0", port=5001)
```

I logged the session and request cookies and I got something like:

> <SecureCookieSession {}>
> ImmutableMultiDict([])
> ImmutableMultiDict([])
> <SecureCookieSession {'state': '1AeB...vRhDjr21'}>
> ImmutableMultiDict([('session', 'eyJzdGF0ZSI6Ijhyj96QmWMDtX2Bo')])
> <SecureCookieSession {'access_token': 'BQAEOHsU-bndcryqB9dqAJ0dfXTg08PJ54OiIoRJeSlG-52V4iSYQcd9Q7cvSx...5yCb8r8Zet180cYz3v6ZS4LiV', 'refresh_token': 'AQDOQhiSSlmbFec1HLqJ_LzwdJ...uHj6qIYnvx4AfFakJ9HkOi0S4yRyxQY78'}>
> ImmutableMultiDict([('session', '.eJw90MmSojAAANB_4dxUQQgN6R...F8ZuQ.uaR3skGciedjz17ZN_OSLH8gIDs')])
> <SecureCookieSession {}>
> ImmutableMultiDict([])

I also tried using different browsers (e.g. chrome and firefox). I could be something with my frontend but from what I've researched, session is dependent on the browser mostly. I'm not sure what else to test to isolate the cause of the issue. Only thing I haven't tried is testing my flask server on another computer. I'm using a MacBook on Montery if that matters. Any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

perhaps change CORS?

```
from flask_cors import CORS

# ...

app = Flask(__name__)
CORS(app, supports_credentials=True)
```

Then for the fetch...

```
fetch('http://127.0.0.1:5001/is_logged_in', {
  method: 'GET',
  credentials: 'include',
})
  .then((response) => response.json())
  .then((data) => console.log(data));
```